# JUNG - How can MouseOver change thicknes of Vertex and Edges

Tags: java, graph, mouseover, jung, jung2

I'm developing a tool and want, that user can simply choose a vertex or edge.

Now, i'm looking for a way how to change the thickness(highlighting) of a vertex or edge during hovering with the mouse.

And I want increase the size of a vertex or edge, if i zoom into it. At the moment, they will be smaller, i zoom near.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

PS: i use vv.setVertexToolTipTransformer for showing the name of the vertex during hovering, but it don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have placed the code for the thickness and color into the toolTipTransformer e.g. vv.setVertexToolTipTransformer. In this way it works, but the tooltips  appear too late.